# I have a website with two languages. Should I use a Keyword strategy for each language?

Tags: seo, keywords, internationalization, language

My website has two languages and different URLs for each language. The site is about learning English but the company is Spanish (and located in Spain). We also sell online courses for English students anywhere.

Should I develop a Keyword strategy for English and for Inglés? or should I just concentrate on one of the two?

Comment: Who is your target audience?

Comment: By and large, the SEO mechanism is the same, however, because different language emphasis and structure can vary in how one would say something, then there should be a difference in how people search not only be language but regions of the world too. *This is an excellent question!* The answer is likely Yes. But what that is I could not tell you. I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My target audience is Spain for face to face students but the world for the online courses.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure all your pages in both languages are SEO optimized.  Producing content in multiple languages is often a good recipe for multiplying the amount of SEO traffic you get.

The only reason to prefer one over the other would be if one tends to outpace the other by an order of magnitude.  For example if you find that your online courses can get many times more users than your content targeted at Spain, then concentrate on that.   However, you generally don't know that until you try them both.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you have to optimize for the people. A search query in Spanish will be different that an English query. You have to optimize for both if they are your segment. I would approach them as two different websites with different link building strategies, keyword planning etc. At the end of the day you should put more effort at the segment that generates you more traffic.